# Where to put a GLOBAL .css file for ALL apps to use in Django project?

Tags: python, django

I've seen similar questions asked on SO, but from the searching I've done I haven't found an answer for this.

I know that you can have a `static` folder in both the project level, and the app level. I have a `.css` file that I would like ALL apps to utilize. I would think this belongs in the `project`'s static folder, but I don't know how to "access" it from my app's `template.html` file.

My project's tree structure looks like this:

```
| Website
    | templates
        - base.html
    | static
        | css
            - style.css
    | Main_Project
        | apps
            | Main_App
                | templates
                    - app_template.html
                | migrations
                - admin.py
                - models.py
                - ...
```

The relevant part of my `settings.py` looks like this:

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR) + "/media/"

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory that holds static files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR) + "/static/"

# URL that handles the static files served from STATIC_ROOT.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And the `app_template.html` which is supposed to load the `.css` file looks like this:

```
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://127.0.0.1:8083/projects/" />
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css"%}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="bg-img"></div>
<div class="w3-display-middle">
    <h1 class="w3-xxxlarge w3-animate-top text-shadow">Welcome back, {{ current_visitor.visitor_name }}!</h1>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So I'm assuming I'm getting this error:

`[17/Jun/2022 20:00:12] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798`

...because it's trying to look inside the APP's static folder, which does not contain that path. How can I modify this so that it looks in the (let's call it) "global" static folder?

Answer (score 0):

Given another read through [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/), it appears that `static` folders are APP DEPENDENT, and it's only after you run `collectstatic` that it gathers all app's `static` stuff into the parent `STATIC_ROOT` folder. Feel free to correct me here, but that's my assumption thus far.

Comment: Have you setup the urlpatterns in your project folder urls.py file. And you assumption there is correct.
 
`urlpatterns  += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`
`urlpatterns  += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`